# Gradle - Exclude dependencies of dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I'm moving my project to use Gradle. And I have a set of my own dependencies I want to be included in the final jar

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: 'latest.release'

    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-core', version: 'latest.release'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: 'latest.release'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-sqs', version: 'latest.release'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: 'latest.release'
    // etc
```

but they have their own dependencies that I don't want to be included. How do I include ONLY e.g. `commons-io:commons-io:latest.release` without resolving their dependencies?

I tried

```
configurations {
    compileClasspath.transitive = false
}
```

but in this case all my dependencies are excluded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following (working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64473840)):

```
dependencies {
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:latest.release') {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```

Note that `commons-io` is not the best example, as it [does not have](https://search.maven.org/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.8.0/jar) runtime dependencies.